# Import / Sync Google Calendar Events with Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, google-calendar

I see lots of "how to" guides regarding getting Facebook events into a Google Calendar.  But I need to go the *other* way: GCal > Facebook.  The events could show up either in the standard FB "events" page or in some kind of GCal widget I could embed on a FB page.

I know that GCal provides URLs for various export formats of a calendar, but I don't know how (if it's even possible) to import that into FB.  And I also need the syncronization to be automatic: if I update the GCal with a new event, for example, that event should show up automatically on my FB page.

Is this type of import / synchronization possible?  Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: From what I can see is that your can sync facebook events with google calendar, but not google calendar with facebook events? Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook isn't a calendar management application. There's no native method of importing events. If you have the skills, you can create your own application for that. Facebook.StackOverflow [has plenty of discussions](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/search?q=create+event).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways I know of.
The first way, which I haven't tested out because I've never used the site, is Zapier. There are various actions you can choose on [this page](https://zapier.com/app/explore?services=facebook,google-calendar) which seem to include posting events as they are created. I don't know how the post will look, if it works with recurring events, or if it works with user accounts or Like pages only, but it seems likely to be a good fit. There are also choices to post an event shortly before the event if you want to use multiple actions.

The second option is with your calendar's rss feed. You can get the xml link to your Gcal in the individual calendar's settings(hover over the calendar's name in the sidebar, click the arrow that shows up, and choose "Calendar settings") and use an rss-to-Facebook service like RSS Graffiti, IFTTT, Zapier or Networked Blogs(I am not affiliated with any of these) to post new items to your Facebook page. Google Calendar organizes the rss feed by date created, rather than by the event date. The benefit is that things are posted to FB within an hour(depending on rss-to-FB service) of making the Gcal event. The drawback is that recurring events are only posted when they are created, but not when they happen again. Also the details will be formatted like this:

```
When: [date/time]
[unnecessary space]
Who: [your name, and this line only shows on events shared with you]
Where: [this line only shows if a location was specified]
Event Status: confirmed
```

An rss-to-FB service might have the option of leaving out the details, but the event date is only in the description. The event status is odd to include in a FB post and will get repetitive being on every post, so this may not be optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Zapier has a recipe that can do this.

I've just set it up and tested it and it seems to work well. It creates a new Facebook Page Event when a new Google Calendar entry is created.

So far, I've only got it triggering when a new event is created in G Cal, but it might be possible to get it to go through the G Cal diary and transfer existing events.

The recipe is named "Create Facebook Page Event from Google Calendar Event" and is here:
http://zpr.io/GDDa

Currently they have a free plan which allows you 100 tasks/month, running the recipe every 15 minutes. If you want more tasks or more frequent runs then they make you pay.

You have to give it (at least) read-access to the Google Calendar, and write access to the Facebook Page (obviously).

Comment: This recipe seems to be gone. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: This, perhaps: https://zapier.com/apps/facebook-pages/integrations/google-calendar/3314/post-a-google-event-calendar-entry-to-facebook-pages-post

Comment: This doesn't actually create a facebook *event*, it creates a facebook-page post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying SmartStack, with some reasonable success, though not everything I want.
I create a TAB for the calendar, and use the Code widget to post the ical link you can get from your Google calendar

Answer (score -1):

You can have a try at either:

- [this facebook app](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=322170575766) - in alpha version though
- [this blog post](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/02/15/how-to-sync-facebook-events-with-google-calendar/) which explains how you can export your events from Facebook and read them in your Google Calendar

Comment: The OP asked for importing events into FB.

Comment: JMax, that first link you have to the facebook app appears to be broken. Does someone have a solution for this? I'm looking for the same thing, an app for auto-importing iCal or GCal data into a Facebook page's Events.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a good answer.  I just posted a HTML link to the Calendar under the "organization" "tab" at the upper left of the fb page (under the profile pic) It's not highly visible, but it's there. Or you can post a link to the calendar in a post and pin the post to the top of your fb page so it's always there.

Answer (score -1):

I've been using http://www.iframe-apps.com/ and so far so good. Although it has limited customization options.

Comment: Per the [FAQ#promotion] *"you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."*  Please expand your answer to disclose your affiliation and/or reasons for suggesting.

Answer (score -1):

Write some PHP to use the [Facebook API to create events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) using events that you [pull out of GCal](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList).

Comment: Servus! Why some PHP? I think this is more a comment then an answer...

Comment: Please add some more context to this answer or some possible open source tools already written to provide this solution.

Answer (score -1):

use www.ifttt.com. it has a way to put google events onto your facebook wall. you only have to set it up once to post all google calendar events onto your faceboook wall and you're done. it will post gcal events to fb until you tell it to stop. downside...it only dos this 15min. before each event. dont know why you cant change this. if someone figures out how please post here.

Answer (score -1):

Ok there is away, I just did it for the 3rd time today.
What you need is a Static HTML Facebook app. http://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/
Add that to your page the go into it and edit the html section.
Then open your gmail account go into the calendar settings and get your html from there for your calendar.
Then past it into your static HTML app on Facebook and your done,
Everything you edit in that gmail account will automatically appear in your Facebook page. All done.

Comment: How does this actually import these as calendar events? This would just _show_ them, not _import_ them.

Comment: Well try this one then if you don't want html page.http://apps.facebook.com/icalendar-to-event/

Comment: That link doesn't appear to go anywhere. Also, if you want to recommend that then you should edit it into your answer _and_ explain how it works.